# Power BI Drill through get avg instead of Sum on a calculated measure

Tags: powerbi

I have a calculated measure as shown below in the images. On my lowest level which is weekly I get correct values but when I roll up to month level, Power BI sums up all the weekly data. I was wondering if there is any possible way Power BI gives me avg of all the weeks in a month instead of summing it up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any possibility to get the measure that you've written?

Comment: Hey @AmilaMGunawardana I was able to resolve this. Thanks.